# FileStat behavior changed in 1.7.3

Tags: java, google-app-engine

When upgrading to GAE (Java) 1.7.3 this test started failing against local GAE instance:

```
@Test
public void testStats() throws Exception {
   AppEngineFile file = service.createNewBlobFile("text/plain", "records123.txt");
   writeToFileAndFinalize(file, "This is content.");
   FileStat stat = service.stat(file);
   Assert.assertNotNull(stat);
   Assert.assertTrue(stat.isFinalized());
   Assert.assertEquals("records123.txt", stat.getFilename());
   Assert.assertTrue(stat.getLength() > 0);
}
```

Failed tests:   testStats(org.jboss.test.capedwarf.files.test.FilesTestCase): expected:<[records123.txt]> but was:<[/blobstore/writable:R45VqzenfR-tGfHPVFWa-A]>

Bug or feature?